# Correct way of dynamically loading .NET framework assemblies of current version

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a `.NET` application compiled on a certain version of the `.NET framework`.

At `runtime` it should be able to dynamically load some assemblies to be used as references for some `C#` code to be compiled and emitted in a new assembly.
I would like the application to be able to load some basic assemblies, such as `mscorlib`, `System`, `System.Core`, etc, without having to specify their physical path or version. I would like the assemblies of the same framework version as the application to be loaded.

`Class System.Reflection.Assembly` has many methods to load assemblies (many are obsolete/deprecated!), but I don't manage to find a suitable one.

Is there a clean way of loading framework's assemblies with currently executing framework version?

Comment: I am curious, why do you need to load them manually/dynamically, instead of referencing them in the project?

Comment: @Dmytro ShevchenkoI: my application is supposed to be a kind of "C# script engine", to be used just for some diagnostics; I would like it to automatically load a set of predefined assemblies, before compiling the script and execute it.